# RNetLogo works on R3.1.1.0?

Tags: java, r, netlogo

When I try to launch the RNetLogo from R using the function NLStart(). I get messages about java and the GUI does not open. I am using MacOsX 10.9.5 64-bit, NetLogo 5.1.0, and R 3.1.1.

```
> library(rJava)
> library(RNetLogo)
> nl.path <- "/Applications/NetLogo\ 5.1.0/NetLogo\ 5.1.0.app"
> NLStart(nl.path, nl.version=5, gui=FALSE)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/nlogo/workspace/Controllable
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at RJavaClassLoader.findClass(RJavaClassLoader.java:383)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 2 more
```

After that I try with "JGR and Deducer and deducer extras”.
The code and errors are:

```
> install.packages(c("JGR","Deducer","DeducerExtras”))
> Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)
> library(JGR)
> Sys.unsetenv("NOAWT")
> JGR()
```

When start JGR the code is:

```
Loading required package: JGR
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: JavaGD
Loading required package: iplots
starting httpd help server ... done
Loading required package: RNetLogo
Loading required package: DeducerExtras
Loading required package: Deducer
Loading required package: ggplot2
Use suppressPackageStartupMessages to eliminate package startup messages.
Loading required package: car
Loading required package: MASS
Attaching package: ‘Deducer’
Loading required package: irr
Loading required package: lpSolve

> nl.path<-"/users/Pabolo/Applications/NetLogo\ 5.1.0/NetLogo.jar"
> NLStart(nl.path)
Error on setwd(nl.path) : you can not change the working directory.
```

With nl.path be the path to the app dir. 
There are some errors. 
I running all these over JGR().

```
> nl.path<-"/Applications/NetLogo\ 5.1.0"
> NLStart(nl.path)
Warning: ch.randelshofer.quaqua.util.OSXPreferences failed to load /Users/Pabolo/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
java.io.IOException: parseReal: unsupported byte count:128
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.util.BinaryPListParser.parseReal(BinaryPListParser.java:703)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.util.BinaryPListParser.parseObjectTable(BinaryPListParser.java:424)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.util.BinaryPListParser.parse(BinaryPListParser.java:315)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXPreferences.readPList(OSXPreferences.java:176)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXPreferences.updateCache(OSXPreferences.java:99)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXPreferences.ensureCached(OSXPreferences.java:90)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXPreferences.get(OSXPreferences.java:79)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.osx.OSXPreferences.getString(OSXPreferences.java:45)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.BasicQuaquaLookAndFeel.initSystemColorDefaults(BasicQuaquaLookAndFeel.java:151)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.leopard.Quaqua15LeopardLookAndFeel.initSystemColorDefaults(Quaqua15LeopardLookAndFeel.java:208)
    at ch.randelshofer.quaqua.BasicQuaquaLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicQuaquaLookAndFeel.java:76)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:520)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:564)
    at org.nlogo.swing.Utils.setSystemLookAndFeel(Utils.java:41)
    at org.nlogo.app.App.<init>(App.scala:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:147)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:332)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:272)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:354)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:692)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:671)
    at org.nlogo.app.App$.main(App.scala:140)
    at org.nlogo.app.App.main(App.scala)
    at nlcon.NLink_v5.<init>(NLink_v5.java:96)
    at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.rniRunMainLoop(Native Method)
    at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.run(Rengine.java:640)
unable to find translation for: edit.viewSettings.2D.frameRate in GUI_Strings for locale: es
unable to find translation for: edit.viewSettings.2D.frameRate.info in GUI_Strings for locale: es
>
```

Comment: Shouldn't nl.path just be the path to the dir not the app? (As per you first ref to it). This package is a bit whack the way it controls this, but I think that is your fix. I do not use mac but this def works in 3.1.0

Comment: There are some errors with that. Is a problem between Java, MacOsx, RNetlogo and R???. I doing every thing right?

Comment: You may need to send the URL of your question directly to the maintainers of the R extension to get their attention here; I don't think they monitor Stack Overflow.

Comment: Check if the folder you supply exists and you have writing permission on it, because you get the error message: "you can not change the working directory."

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your path to: `nl.path <- "/Applications/NetLogo 5.3/app"`.

They have changed the directory structure so that the netlogo jar file is now in an 'app' subdirectory.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837036/468305

Hope that helps, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It says you can not change your working directory. Maybe start a new session. Also one of your backslashes is going the wrong way.

To find your NetLogo path try `file.choose()` and then navigate to the NetLogo Jar file. Then when you open the path to file will show in R studios console. Copy the file path into the NLStart command which should look something like below.

```
file.choose()
NLStart("C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.2.0\\app", gui = TRUE, nl.jarname = "netlogo-6.2.0.jar")
```

Finally, make sure your Java, NetLogo and R are all running on 64 bit (works for me) or 32 bit but try not to mix. Finally try and run code directly from R GUI instead of RStudio. This helped the first time I opened Netlogo with R.

I have a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWMdaTEPTOc) explaining how to open NetLogo from R and all my functional code (August 2021) can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonysdatamodels/netlogo.in.r/main/open%20netlogo%20in%20r).